# Mouse over events in d3heatmap plots

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, d3heatmap

I want to create a shiny app that gives the data corresponding to a particular spot in in the heatmap in a separate table.

In shiny.ui

```
d3heatmapOutput("HeatPlot", click = "plot1_click" ),
tableOutput("Table")
```

And then in the shiny.server

```
output$HeatPlot <- renderD3heatmap(d3heatmap(inc1, scale = 'column',Colv = NA,
                                   Rowv = NA,col = rainbow(256)))
```

Then when the user clicks on any spot on the heatmap a table is shown containing the values at that point in the table.

```
output$Table <- renderTable({
      if (is.null(input$plot1_click$x)) return()
      else {
        keeprows <- round(input$plot1_click$x) == as.numeric(Data)
        head(Data[keeprows, ], 10)
```

But when i run the app error like

```
Error in d3heatmapOutput("HeatPlot", click = "plot1_click") : 
                      unused argument (click = "plot1_click")
```

Comes. Is the click function not valid for d3heatmap? Or am i to instal something before dong this? Please help.

The dataframe inc1 is somthing like

[image]

**OR**

If i use heatmap.2 or heatmap
 with same shiny.ui but

```
inc1 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlot(heatmap(inc1, scale = 'column',Colv = NA, Rowv = NA,
                                                                        col = rainbow(256)))
```

I get

```
Warning: Error in renderTable: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

What is it that i should do?

Comment: Hi. You shoud give a complete reproducible example to increase your chances to get an answer.

Comment: What more should i add to the question? @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example, not only fragments of your code. In this way we can copy-paste and run.